# Get HTML styled text from TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, jlabel

I have a textview, and there is a HTML styled text on it like this on `H<sub>2</sub>O`. I want to get that text from `TextView`, I tried to get string from it `( getText().toString() )`, but it brings the text without subscription like this `H2O`.

How can I get text from `textview` with subscription?

Comment: You are trying to mix content with presentation. Here H2O is content and subscription is its presentation.

Comment: How can I get the content with presentation

Comment: You cant get it like that, instead get that text and again append the styled text to it

Comment: You are already getting it by displaying as HTML

Comment: How can I get it styled as a variable

Comment: How can I get it as code of HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can save HTML version of text via setTag / getTag if you really need to. However, you should have this data as some object representation.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Html.toHtml(textView.getText())`